# create source code to be attached in Scala IDE

Tags: jar, sbt, scala-ide, sbt-assembly

I have two scala projects. One(A) is in Scala IDE(and not using sbt) and the other (B) is using sbt and not Scala IDE.
What I currently do is that I produce a fat JAR using sbt assembly of B and add it in the A's scala IDE build path  as an external JAR.
Unfortunately the source code is not attached.
I would like to produce a fat JAR that contained already the source code(if that is possible at all), but assembly does not seem to have that option.
If not possible, I would like to produce a zip file with my source code so that I can attach the JAR to it, but I am not sure which folder(s) I should zip. Is there a sbt plugin that does that? How to find out which folders I should zip? B is slightly complex and I really don't understand its folder structure.

Comment: Are you wanting just (B)'s source code, or the source code of (B) and all of its dependencies? Also, couldn't you just `publishLocal` (B) and depend on it normally within (A)?

Comment: Just B's source code would already be nice. Is publishLocal sbt command publish-local? What would be "depend normally"?

Comment: Yes, I mean `sbt publish-local` (`publishLocal` also works). "normally" means via a declared dependency on the library. If you're publishing version `0.0.1` of your `B` library, you'd add a maven dependency in project `A` on something like `org.myorg.B:B_2.11:0.0.1`. I'm not sure how dependencies are declared in Scala IDE.

Comment: i'm not sure either how maven dependencies are to be used in eclipse and can't find good info about it , so it would just change a problem for another one. publish-local does prodices a zip with the source files, bit attaching them the fat jar I have does not work

Comment: If you use standard dependency declarations (like maven ones), your IDE will know where to find the source jars. It's one of the key benefits of such a system. You'll also have source jars for all of your dependencies.